# Get X Axis value on the Click of Chart - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have come across a strange requirement.

> I need to get X-Axis value from chart when user clicks on Chart Area.

I know we can assign a macro to a chart. So in way, event for the chart can be created. But no idea of how to proceed further.

Any idea to do this please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your Chart is in a Chart Sheet then you can right click on the Chart sheet tab, select "View code" and paste the following in its code module (see screenshot below)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Chart_Select(ByVal ElementID As Long, ByVal Arg1 As Long, ByVal Arg2 As Long)
    Select Case ElementID
    Case xlSeries
       If Arg2 > 0 Then
           MsgBox "Series " & Arg1 & vbCr & "Point " & Arg2
       End If
    Case Else
       MsgBox Arg1 & vbCr & Arg2
    End Select
End Sub
```

[image]

If your chart is embedded in a sheet then you will have to use `WithEvents` as @brettdj has already covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431586/vba-chart-click-excel)

**FOLLOWUP**

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub Chart_Select(ByVal ElementID As Long, ByVal Arg1 As Long, ByVal Arg2 As Long)
    Select Case ElementID
    Case xlSeries
        If Arg2 > 0 Then
            x = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Arg1).XValues
            For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
                If i = Arg2 Then
                    MsgBox "Point :" & i & "and X Value = " & x(i)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
       End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you but I think it's not giving correct x-axis value. Can you please have a look once again?

Comment: Can I see your sample file?

Comment: Yeah sure. [Here is the file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7gzonuQsNbvaVdwNHRaWEhLdWM/edit?usp=sharing) in which I have created chart sheet by following your instructions. [Link to File](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7gzonuQsNbvaVdwNHRaWEhLdWM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: See Followup in my post above

Comment: Hi, No matter wherever I click, I am getting Arg2 as <=0 always. Where exactly should I click on chart sheet to get the x-axis value? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the latest code that I posted? You shouldn't be getting any messagebox if you click anywhere else in the code. You will only get a messagebox if you click anywhere on the series. (maybe you haven't refreshed this page?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27188/discussion-between-tejas-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: **If Arg2 > 0 Then** condition is never satisfying. Perhaps I'm clicking on a wrong area or the code is hardware dependent