# Selecting point on scatter diagram and retrieving the values of point - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a scatter diagram that I which to retrieve data from by using some sort of macro. I want to be able to select a dot/point on the scatter diagram, run the macro and show the values. I have seeen a few version on stack which are not working for me. Any ideas?

Comment: "I have seen a few version on stack which are not working for me"  -which specific one(s), and how are they not working for you?

Comment: Chart sheet or embedded on a worksheet?

Comment: I had one version which only returned zero ( which i cannot find the link for anymore) and this version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703967/get-x-axis-value-on-the-click-of-chart-excel-vba which I honestly do not understand fully.

Comment: A chart sheet. I have table in sheet1 and create a chart based on this table which is also found in sheet1

Comment: Sorry, I meant embedded on a worksheet

Comment: there was a post similar today or yesterday. Look for chart class module, something like that. Can't look now, having a storm and am on phone browsing. Edit: Found it anyways: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/76378479?noredirect=1