# VBA Excel 2010 - Run code when selecting chart legend

Tags: vba, excel, charts

Currently what I am trying to do I don't know if it is even possible and I dont even know where to begin (I have tried [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431586/catch-event-on-chart-click) but I am unable to get it to even work).

I am trying to get a macro to run automacticly when clicking the legend of a chart, I know you can assign a macro to charts to run them that way but if possible I would like to do this from the charts legend. The code I would like to run is below, it is a simple toggle to turn the chart lines on/off

```
If ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue Then
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
ElseIf ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse Then
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
End If
```

If this isnt possible I can honestly see why but if there are any ideas on work arounds that to would be great

**Edit:**

I made a small mistake in what I was looking to do here, sorry, I would like the code to run when clicking an legend entry, this is the text part of the legend next to the coloured line (so Chart line 1, Chart line 1 etc etc), hopefully this clarifys it

Comment: Is this a chart sheet? If not but a embedded chart within a worksheet, how familiar are you with class programming in Excel vba?

Comment: @Axel Richter , It is a embedded chart, and not too familiar with class programming sorry

Comment: @AxelRichter , I tell a lie I do know class programming a bit but I havent used it much

Comment: http://peltiertech.com/chart-events-microsoft-excel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes, you have your embedded chart object as the first chart object in the first worksheet.

I have the following in Sheet1:
[image]

Create a class module. Name it `clsChartEvents`. In that class module put the following code:

```
Public WithEvents myChart As Chart

Private Sub myChart_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)

 Dim ElementID As Long, Arg1 As Long, Arg2 As Long

 With myChart

  .GetChartElement x, y, ElementID, Arg1, Arg2

  If ElementID = xlLegendEntry Then
   If .SeriesCollection(Arg1).Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue Then
    .SeriesCollection(Arg1).Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
   ElseIf .SeriesCollection(Arg1).Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse Then
    .SeriesCollection(Arg1).Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
   End If
   .ClearToMatchStyle
  End If

 End With

End Sub
```

`.GetChartElement x, y, ElementID, Arg1, Arg2` **gets** the `ElementID`, `Arg1` and `Arg2` from the mouse click position x, y.

In a default module put the following code:

```
Dim myChartWithEvents As clsChartEvents

Sub init()
 Set myChartWithEvents = New clsChartEvents
 Set oChart = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Chart
 Set myChartWithEvents.myChart = oChart
End Sub
```

Now run the sub `init` and click the legend entries.

A click on the legend entry should switch the corresponding line on/off.

Comment: I am slightly stunned by how quick you came up with an answer, I dont think there is enough +1s to give but this will be fun to play with to try and get to work with multiple chart lines

Comment: To distinguish the legend entries, have a look at the `Arg1`.

Comment: Nope I tried for as long as I could but I cant get it to change a different line of a chart, I have tried changing `Arg1` and `Arg2` but Nothing happens or it still changes Chart line 1, how you managed this without being able to step through I dont know, but i can only praise you more for it

Comment: You have possible not realized, that the `.GetChartElement x, y, ElementID, Arg1, Arg2` **gets** the ElementID, Arg1 and Arg2 from the mouse click position x, y. See my supplement.

Comment: Ok that was my fault, not sur ehow much instead of `.SeriesCollection(Arg1)` I had `.SeriesCollection(1)`, now I have changed it it works perfectly, sorry for the bother

Answer (score 1):

As an easy workaround you could draw a rectangle-form over the legend. You can format that rectangle with no interior and no line making it invisible and even group chart and rectangle so that both can be moved around together.

You can link that rectangle to you macro then. In your macro you can't use 'ActiveChart' but have to identify the correct chart with name or id. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have updated the question, your idea wasnt bad but wasnt what I was after but that was my fault with the way I worded the question

Comment: No problem. If your chart (especially the number of Lines) is static you can still use the offered solution and one rectangle for every legend entry. I think this is the only way to get your expected results with just one click...

Comment: Yea unfortunatlly there is going to be multiple charts, and even more created, but I can look into code for creating that, still I like your answer